# How do I 'gather' two different sets of columns in R at the same time?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I have a data frame where one set of columns name the 'question' that a participant saw and the values under these columns specify whether the participant's answer was true or false. The second set of columns specify what the participants' answers were. The following dummy data set should illustrate the logic.

```
Name <- c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Tina")
Question1 <- c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0)
Question1_answer <- c(22, 35, 22, 22, 90)
Question2 <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
Question2_answer <- c(75, 72, 11, 43, 75)
Question3 <- c(0,0,1,0,1)
Question3_answer <- c(16, 18, 19, 27, 19)

df <- data.frame(Name, Question1, Question1_answer, Question2, Question2_answer, Question3, Question3_answer)
print(df)
```

Instead, I want this data frame to look as follows:

```
Name <- rep(c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Tina"), 3)
Question <- rep(c("Question1", "Question2", "Question3"), each=5)
Answer <- rep(c(Question1_answer, Question2_answer, Question3_answer))
Score <- rep(c(Question1, Question2, Question3))

df2 <- data.frame(Name, Question, Answer, Score)
print(df2)
```

How can I make this happen? (Ideally in one step.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it in "one run" we have to modify the names with `rename_with`:

With `rename_with` we create pairs of columns. One ending with `Score` the second ending with `answer` and both separate by `_`. At the same time we do not touch `Name`.

Next we can make use of our new colnames in `pivot_longer` using the argument `names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)"` which means we have two words separate by an `_` (by the way, it is equivalent to `names_sep= "_"`).

And now we can take advantage of the mysterious but wonderful `.value` argument, which is used to specify the **name** of the new column that will contain the values that are currently spread across multiple columns (in our case `Score` and in the second way `answer`):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  rename_with(~ paste0(., "_Score"), .cols = all_of(names(.)[!grepl("_", names(.)) & names(.) != "Name"])) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Question"), 
               names_to = c("Question", ".value"), 
               names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)") %>% 
  arrange(Question)
```

```
   Name  Question  Score answer
   <chr> <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 Jon   Question1     1     22
 2 Bill  Question1     0     35
 3 Maria Question1     1     22
 4 Ben   Question1     1     22
 5 Tina  Question1     0     90
 6 Jon   Question2     1     75
 7 Bill  Question2     0     72
 8 Maria Question2     0     11
 9 Ben   Question2     0     43
10 Tina  Question2     1     75
11 Jon   Question3     0     16
12 Bill  Question3     0     18
13 Maria Question3     1     19
14 Ben   Question3     0     27
15 Tina  Question3     1     19
```

As an alternative:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Question"),
               names_to = "Question",
               values_to = "Score") %>%
  mutate(Answer = lead(Score), .before=Score) %>% 
  slice(which(row_number() %% 2 != 0)) %>% 
  arrange(Question)
```